# Access javascript var from the scope above in nested function

Tags: javascript

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
function doSomething() { 
    var clipId;
    funtion doSomethingElse(clipId) {
        this.clipId = clipId;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work because `this` points to window object and `clipId` is not a global variable, it's defined in the `doSomething` function.

I know I can change the name of the argument that I pass to the second function, so for example I can change the name of the `clipId` argument to `clipId1`, and then just do `clipId = clipId1` in the second function.But, I don't want that. I want the var and the argument to have the same name.

Comment: *I want the var and the argument to have the same name*. Why? More basically, I can't see how you're going to be able to call `doSomethingElse` at all, since it's not accessible outside `doSomething`.

Comment: Why you need to have a same variable names? `doSomethingElse` is in `doSomething` scope, why you need to pass a `clipId`, which is already available?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this without changing either name. If you shadow a variable from a parent scope with a local variable, it becomes inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a setter.

```
function doSomething() { 
    var clipId;
    function setClipId(value) {
        clipId = value;
    }
    function doSomethingElse(clipId) {
        setClipId(clipId);
    }
}
```

But I guess you hope there is some syntax allowing to do that without those kind of additional constructs. Then, the right answer is [Matti's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672820/1178314) imo.

Comment: Sure, but you have gone to all this trouble in order to accommodate a completely meaningless condition posed by the OP, which is that he inexplicably wants to intentionally shadow a variable by using the same name.

Comment: The OP actual need probably takes place in a more complex context. Either I ask him more context if I wish to elaborate some better workaround for his case, or I give some answer that may suits him. I do not assume the snippet reflects exactly his actual context.

Comment: Right. We have asked for more context, but he hasn't answered yet. Let's wait.

Answer (score 0):

Because of "closure" in JavaScript, you don't need the argument at all.
This will work:

```
function doSomething () { 
    var clipId;
    funtion doSomethingElse () {
        this.clipId = clipId;
    }
}
```

because `doSomethingElse()` has access to the variables in its scope (in this case, to `doSomething()`'s variable `clipId`.